# How can I print 6 numbers in ascending order without randomly overlapping the numbers?

Tags: python, printing, numbers, auto, overlapping

Sharing Lotto, the largest lottery in Korea, is conducted by selecting 6 different numbers from 1 to 45. The number of sharing lotto can be selected by the buyer himself, but it can also be selected in an "automatic" way that is left to the machine.
Write a program that meets the following conditions so that you can participate in the Sharing Lotto in an 'automatic' manner.

Conditions:

1. Creating a Function
2. Return a list of six different integers from 1 to 45 as elements
3. Returned lists are sorted in ascending order
4. Print the returned list on the screen

Example of 10 iterations of a function that satisfies a condition:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRg5U.png)

What code should I use to program like this?

umm guys, i want code. i have not error guys

Comment: Can you post some of your work, so that we can fix errors?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a homework question with no attempt from the author to write any of their own code

Comment: kindly have a look on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
ans = []

while len(ans)<6 :
  x = random.randrange(0,45,1)
  if x in ans:
    pass
  else:
    ans.append(x)
ans.sort()
print(ans)
```

@Aiden this should work, turns out maybe you are not allowed to use numpy

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework question, please share your failed approach and I will be happy to correct you.

```
import numpy as np

ans = []

while len(ans)<6 :
  x = np.random.randint(45)+1
  if x in ans:
    pass
  else:
    ans.append(x)
ans.sort()
print(ans)
```

New approach without importing numpy

```
import random
ans = []

while len(ans)<6 :
  x = random.randrange(0,45,1)
  if x in ans:
    pass
  else:
    ans.append(x)
ans.sort()
print(ans)
```

Comment: This should not be posted as an answer. I realize you do not have enough reputation to comment, so I suggest taking a look at [what you should do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174)

Comment: @12944qwerty I have fixed it.

Comment: thanks but i work in rur-ple.
so it may not work... sorry.. any other way?

Comment: have you tried it @Aiden1L8L

Comment: yes, but it's not working...:(

Comment: i must work in rurple, so sorry but it's not working..

Comment: umm i think import is not working on rurple :(
if you want about rurple, visit https://sourceforge.net/projects/rur-ple/files/ and check out rurple

Comment: Fixed it on new answer try it and let me know.

Comment: gee, thank you very much!!
i found the way using you're answer! thx!  :)

Comment: mark it as solved @Aiden1L8L

Comment: yes, i did it Aavesh, thanks for helping!